# Finding criteria for a household financial budget falsification

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions, finance, economics

I’m working on a financial problem about budget of households. Households in a state fill a form about their net budget in every year and our insurance company investigate their financial status and find the exact amount of their budget. **The net budget can be positive or negative**. I’m designing a system with neural network that we can find the households that Falsify their net budget, So my output is a binary [ 0 and 1] which 1 is false net budget and  0 is true net budget.

Suppose that households’ net budget is P and our investigated outcome of net budget is R. As you know :

```
R>=P
```

Now we have this:

```
If P=R then  :  Criterion = 0 (true net budget)
If P>0 and R>0   :  Criterion = R-P/R 
If P<0 and R<0   :  Criterion = (abs(P)-abs(R)) / abs(P) 
If P<0 and R>0    :  ????     (A lot of households have this situation and I dint find any criterion for it)
If P<0 and R=0    :  ????     (Some of households have this situation and I dint find any criteria for it)
If P=0 and R>0    :  ????      (Some of households have this situation and I dint find any criterion for it)
```

After finding these criterion that **must be between 0 and 1  [0 1]**, I set a threshold (like 0.5), If the criterion is higher than 0.5 household is falsifying the net budget (output = 1) and If it is lower than 0.5 we have a true budget and there isn’t any problem in budget declaring of households (output = 0).

** In range of [0 1], if falsification is higher (depends of above functions - P and R) the creation goes toward 1 and if the household is honest it goes toward 0. So every household (sample) has a criterion between 0 and 1.

1. My main problem is finding a good criterion when `(P<0 , R>0)`, After that `(P<0 , R=0)` and finally `(P=0 , R>0)`. IF I have a problem in first, second and third criterion, feel free to say.
2. I think the output of second situation is different from third because structures of criteria is different. I’m going to find a single criterion function If it is possible.

**Example :**
First conduction : P = 10 , R = 15 : Criteria : (15-10/15) = 33.3% ( falsification rate for this household )
Second conduction : P = -16, R = -10 : Criteria : (abs(-16)-abs(-10))/abs(-16) = 37.5% ( falsification rate for this household )

Now if for example P=-20 and R = 40, How we can calculate falsification rate? . This is main question. after that how we can calculate when (P<0 , R=0) and finally (P=0 , R>0)?

**I check this criterion with this procedure:**
for example in first criterion when P>0 and R>0 we have P = 5 and R = 10 so E = 50% . Now if P=fix = 5 and R=increase ( for example now R= 20) we have E = 75%. This is true conceptually in our problem. We must have more falsification when P=5 and R=20 Compared with P = 5 and R = 10 . + we must check it when R=fix and P=increase (or decrease).

Thank you so much for your helps.

PS.
I Have 2000 samples with different size of P and R.

Comment: Have you considered Benford's law: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law?

Comment: @user99680 I checked your link but I don't know how can I use this Technique in my problem. Can you describe your idea In the context of my problem? thanks.

Comment: Could you give me some time, I need to head out for a while?

Comment: Of course. take your time.

Comment: If you are talking about "Accounting fraud detection" part of Wikipedia page that is a good approach for testing but I have a good guide (Our company detection = R) so I can use more complicated approaches as I mentioned above. So I think I should focus on criteria in different conditions of 'P' and 'R' .

Comment: @user99680 Feel free for creating different criteria with 'P' and 'R' for this problem. thanks.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to come up with something useful, but it is not my area of expertise, sorry.

Comment: @user99680 Thank you anyway :-)